# android webview possible to scroll out of page bounds?

Tags: android, webview, scroll, padding

Is it possible to scroll out of the page bounds in a webview?

Example: Webview page/content width: 15px, screen size: 10px. Can I scroll to X position 8px?

Technically I can, and it worked fine on my test device. However, testing on other devices I notice that it will stop rendering when I move out of the bound. The left part of the page will be 'blurry' or not visible at all, till I scroll back left and there is no more "empty space" in the webview, than it will update.

Is there a solution for this?

A possible solution would be making the content larger on the fly, with white space. But I cannot add padding to the webview, unless I put it in the html BEFORE I render it. But before I render it I won't know the width. After I render it there is no way to change the padding/add some empty space to the content, without loading it completely again. Right?

Comment: can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by added 1-2 page-breaks at the end of the html, it will render fine now and I customly prefent the view from scrolling to the end of the page, so that the white is not shown to the user.